# Can't Route Using NativeScript

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript

I'm pretty new to Angular and NativeScript and am trying to make an app. I have my first page created but I can't quite figure out how to route. The page that I'm trying to route to is my `signInComponent`. Here's what I have:

my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },
    { path: "signIn", loadChildren: "./signIn/signIn.module#SignInModule" }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

my button, which is in `home.component.html`:

```html
<Button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-sm" style="width: 90%; height: 7%; padding: 0px; margin-top: 75%; margin-bottom: 5px; background-color: black; color: white; vertical-align: bottom;" text="Sign In" (tap)=onSignIn()></Button>
```

my `onSignIn()` function, which is in my `home.component.ts`:

```
onSignIn(): void { 
    this.router.navigate(['signIn']);
}
```

here's my `signIn-routing.model.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { SignInComponent } from "./signIn.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: SignInComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class SignInRoutingModule { }
```

my `signIn.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "SignIn",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./signIn.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./signIn.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
    onButtonTap(): void {
        console.log("Button was pressed");
    }


    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

and then here's my signIn.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";
import { NativeScriptUICalendarModule } from "nativescript-ui-calendar/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIChartModule } from "nativescript-ui-chart/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIDataFormModule } from "nativescript-ui-dataform/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIAutoCompleteTextViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-autocomplete/angular";
import { NativeScriptUIGaugeModule } from "nativescript-ui-gauge/angular";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

import { SignInRoutingModule } from "./signIn-routing.module";
import { SignInComponent } from "./signIn.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        NativeScriptUICalendarModule,
        NativeScriptUIChartModule,
        NativeScriptUIDataFormModule,
        NativeScriptUIAutoCompleteTextViewModule,
        NativeScriptUIGaugeModule,
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        SignInRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SignInComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class SignInModule { }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new to Nativescript/Angular myself, but when designing other components, I've been able to get by without declaring `.module.ts` and `.model.ts` files for individual components. I'm not sure if this is best practice (and if it isn't, I'd be more than happy to be corrected), but try importing and adding your `SignInComponent` in the `declarations` array of your `app.module.ts` file and as a route in your `app.routing.ts` file.